# This operation is not allowed on Non-connected sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

Consider the following:

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        clientObject = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 90);
        centralForm.writeLog("Connecting to desired server", System.Drawing.Color.Gray, true);
        clientObject.Connect(ipEnd);
        if ((debug) && (clientObject.Connected)) { Debug.Print("Connected"); }

        Send("0");
        clientObject.GetStream().BeginRead(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, Read, null);
    }
```

I get the error stated above on the last line in this snippet of code. What have I done wrong? I have called Connect()... I've stared at this for ages and I genuinely have no idea what I have done wrong.

Send Code:

```
    public void Send(string data)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(clientObject.GetStream()))
        {
            w.WriteLine(data);
            w.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @c45207 Send function has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `StreamWriter` is disposed (at the end of the `using` block) the used Stream gets also closed.

After the `Send(`) Method you try to use the closed stream resulting in the described exception.

Comment: Hello, How did you fix that issue?