# bluetooth device sometimes connected, sometimes not

Tags: c#, android, wpf, bluetooth

I've been having with this bluetooth. Here is my code:

```
public void createServer()
{
    Thread ServerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServerConnectThread));
    ServerThread.Start();
}

public void ServerConnectThread()
{

    updateUI("Server started");
    updateUI("Waiting for client..");
    BluetoothListener BTListener = new BluetoothListener(UUID);
    BTListener.Stop();
    BTListener.Start();
    ServerRunning = true;
    BluetoothClient conn = BTListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
    MessageBoxResult connected = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Phone has connected", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    if (connected == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            player1Connection.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            player1Connectiondc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }));


    Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();
    while (ServerRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] received = new byte[1];
            mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
            updateUI("Message Received. " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received) + " u too");
            mStream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length);
            updateUI("The code is " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received).ToString();
            updateUI("Key is " + result);

            if (Game != null)
            {

                SinglePlayGame sg = (IceGame.Class.SinglePlayGame)Game;
                force.Y = -force.Y;
                if (result == "A")
                {
                    force += new Vector2(-forceAmount, 0);
                }

                else if (result == "D")
                {
                    force += new Vector2(forceAmount, 0);
                }
                else if (result == "W")
                {
                    force += new Vector2(0, -forceAmount);
                }

                else if (result == "S")
                {
                    force += new Vector2(0, forceAmount);
                }


                sg.BodyPlayer1.ApplyForce(force);
                force = new Vector2(0, 0);
            }


        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
        }
    }
}
```

It will still say that the phone is connected. However the player1Connection will sometimes not be visible also causing the device to not read the commands that I've said. It is working but it takes me around 3 times+ to make the player1Connection work. Please help. THank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (Game != null)
{

    SinglePlayGame sg = (IceGame.Class.SinglePlayGame)Game;
    force.Y = -force.Y;
    if ("A".equals(result))
    {
        force += new Vector2(-forceAmount, 0);
    }

    else if ("D"equals(result))
    {
            force += new Vector2(forceAmount, 0);
    }
    else if ("W".equals(result))
    {
            force += new Vector2(0, -forceAmount);
    }

    else if ("S".equals(result))
    {
            force += new Vector2(0, forceAmount);
    }


        sg.BodyPlayer1.ApplyForce(force);
        force = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }


}
```

Comment: Its already working. However, the problem is within the "player1Connection.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; and player1Connectiondc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden" The code doesn't seem to pass through it and therefore the controls are also not sent to the server pc

Comment: y cant u use `player1Connectiondc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: Still can't. I tihkn the problem is in either this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)((). I'm really not sure about the invoke

Comment: gives me this error. "The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets." from the  Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170301/operation-not-allowed-on-non-connected-sockets-c-sharp-4-0 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924789/this-operation-is-not-allowed-on-non-connected-sockets